# How can I detect a long press then activate an animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

How can I detect a long press on a touch screen then activate an animation? And when the finger is released, play another animation smoothly? Let's take for example the main character in Crossy Road: when the user presses down, the chicken "squats" and when the user releases their finger, the chicken jumps. Same concept. C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool state;
bool calledLong;
float timer;
float timeForLongPress = 1;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        state = true;
        //Write here method you want to call instantly when user presses the button
    }
    if (state) {
        //Write here method you want to call whenever user is holding mouse button
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timer > timeForLongPress) {
            //Write here method you want to call EACH FRAME after user is holding mouse button for more than "timeForLongPress"
            if (!calledLong) {
                calledLong = true;
                //Write here method you want to call only ONCE after user is holding mouse button for more than "timeForLongPress"
            }
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        timer = 0;
        calledLong = false;
        state = false;
    }
}
```

Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0), Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) this is left click, for right click just change 0 to 1 and for middle click change 0 to 2.

If you want to do this for touch (mobile) just change

"Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)" to "Input.touchCount > 0"

and change

"Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)" to "Input.touchCount == 0"

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways but an easy way you can try is

```
Coroutine longPressCoroutine = null;
bool longPress = false;
void Update () {

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        longPressCoroutine = StartCoroutine(PlayerAnimationAfterTime());
    }
    else if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        if(longPressCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(longPressCoroutine);
            // if you want to play second animation only in case of longpress then use this 
            //check otherwise just play your animation here;
            if(longPress)
            {
                //play your second animation here
            }
            longPress = false;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator PlayerAnimationAfterTime()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    //Play your first animation here;
    longPress = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you just don't know how to change animation smoothly, you need to look Mecanim tutorials. It is so simple. just make transition only from first animation to second one. And set smoothness of this transition on inspector.

Then via script trigger first animation when pressed. And trigger second one when released if longpressed.